# Absolute Heat With Kinetic Energy

Tags: temperature, kinetic-theory

I’ve read some of the questions posted here about absolute hot. Planck’s temperature. I understand that that temp comes from the natural units.

Where my question comes into play is when thinking about the kinetic theory of gases. Where K.E. = 3/2 k_bT and K.E. = 1/2mv^2 I would expect the maximum temp to be a function of mass and velocity. While the max velocity of a thing is the speed of light.

I plugged in the mass of a proton and got something on the order of 10^12 K. Which is no where near the 10^32 K or Planck’s temperature . How can I get a proton to Planck’s temperature without it going faster than the speed of light?

Comment: Try using the relativist K.E.

Comment: Did you mean "heat" and not "hot" in the first sentence? And instead of "Heat" in the title, don't you mean "temperature"? Heat is energy transfer between masses due solely to a temperature difference between them. A gas does not contain "heat". The proper term "internal energy".

Comment: Yes. Sorry for not being precise in my language

Comment: No problem, understand.